# NodeJS + HTML5 + Telnet = isitpossible?

Tags: html, node.js, express, websocket, telnet

I have this project for my classes i'm currently workin' on. here it is:

- WebPage client for Telnet not on standard ports, with ability to choose a port and connect

I have machines with telnet servers on them, just waiting for connection.

So my idea was to set up a nodeJS with express server on a dedicated machine. This would handle connections through telnet and host a page for clients, that would use socket.io to exchange information with server side.

But as i'm new to such technologies (telecommunications student) i wonder if it is possible. I spotted something like this - jsterm.com by Peter Nitsch, but i see there are some massive gaps in code and the demo does not really work so i don't know if it actually works. Did anyone try this?

My other problem is - when i send information to nodeJS server through websockets, which seems achievable for me, what do i do with this information? Do i just set up another websocket to pass the same data i got from client websocket directly to the telnet port?

Can sockets connect directly to specific port, without any websocket waiting on the other side?

If my idea is wrong, could anyone help me - maybe there exists some nice solution - i was thinking about Anyterm for example but i see that it requires an apache server and runs completely different technologies...

Comment: Yes, it is feasible. The data flow is that the node server has to setup connections to the telnet server when the terminal emulator in the browser asks and then proxy data to and from it over web sockets.

Comment: why a -1? at least post a comment saying WHY you downvoted. +1

Comment: So it is feasible just to fire messages through websocket to my telnet port in a callback function, that runs everytime websocket from my client receives a message? Server gets message from client, passes it through websocket to telnet port - that's my idea for now :) I will try to run some tests, but i already see that i will need sth like websockify to cut the unrelevant data from my messages just to have a clear binary message that will be inderstood by my telnet server...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to be clear, WebSocket connections are not raw TCP socket connections. They have extra header information in each packet, browser to server data is masked using a running XOR, etc.

In order for the browser to communicate with a normal TCP server (e.g. a telnet server) you will need some sort of bridge service. It just so happens that such a thing already exists. [websockify](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify) is a server that accepts WebSocket connections and bridges them to a raw TCP server.

In fact, the websockify project already includes a working telnet client as an example application. However, note that one limitation of websockify (for security reasons) is that the client cannot pick an arbitrary server address/port to connect to. The target address(es) must be predefined, either as a single target specified on the command line for websockify, or as multiple targets specified in a configuration file (and selected via a token in the WebSocket connect string).

There are multiple implementations of websockify in different languages (python, C, node, ruby, Clojure) however, only the python version currently supports multiple targets via a configuration file.

**Disclaimer**: I created [websockify](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify).

Comment: Yes, Your project seems like a sweet soft solution. Unfortunately, in my app client must be able to decide for himself which port does he want to choose from a list of ports that are used by devices. Is it avalable for example to create an array of websocks that connect nodeJS server to different (may be predefined) telnet port depending on port chosen by client application in a simple web GUI? If it is possible, then i actually have a full setup... I just decided to stick to js and keep it as simple as it can be. Anyway, thanks for Your effort, it's very cool you don't ignore the novice :)

Comment: I figured out another way to do it:

Everytime the new client connects to node via websocket, node sets up a child process "telnet address port" in command line as a child process. Since pretty much every operating system has a telnet client why not to use it?

Everything works pretty fine for me. There is just one bad thing - i guess Windows does not know what sthe stdin and stdout is and i cannot use child_processes there (but it works just fine on Ubuntu 12.04). Anyway, last thing left is to create a good-looking website-based terminal and code will be ready to be posted on Github.

Comment: @kanaka - is this the example you mean? 
https://github.com/novnc/websockify/tree/72ce5c1ae8abbcd3f8bb5f4e93915f61a1047704/include

Comment: @StingyJack yes. Nobody has touched that example in years so it may currently be broken, however, it was working at one time so it should be a reasonable starting point.

Comment: @kanaka - thats fine, I just wanted to confirm I was looking at the right thing